# Badly misconfigured Linux distro meant for hacking?

Tags: linux, security

I remember a while back, someone released a Linux distro that was meant to be hacked or secured as an exercise. Does anyone remember the name? Quite a few Google searches have turned up nothing.

Comment: You may be interested in reading our sister site [security.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean Damn Vulnerable Linux (DVL).

http://www.damnvulnerablelinux.org/

You may find it http://sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_virtualhacking/downloads/os/dvl/DVL_1.5_Infectious_Disease.iso/

Comment: Probably, but that link - and the distro, apparently - are dead.

Comment: http://piratebay.org/torrent/6519397/Damn_Vulnerable_Linux_1.5_-_Infectious_Disease

Answer (score 0):

How about Damn Vulnerable Linux (DVL) - purposely built with as many security holes as possibly and badly configured too. It is usually used to train people on IT security. You can get more info about it in [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=dvl).